# How to check if an interval contains power of two

Tags: java

I'm working on Java. I'd like some help with the following. So, given a specific interval (int low, int high), how can we check if it contains any number that is power of two? My method to check if a number is a power of two is:

```
private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n){
    if( n == 0 || n == 1){
        return false;
    } else if( (n & -n) == n ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method I've done to check if there is any number that is power of two in the interval is:

```
private static boolean ContainsPowerOfTwo(int low, int high){
    boolean f = false ;
    if (isPowerOfTwo(low) || isPowerOfTwo(high)){
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = low; low <= high; i++){
        if ( (low & -low ) == low && low!=0 && low!=1 ) {
            f = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( f == true ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong. If I set the interval to be: (0, 1), I do not get any message on my main program:

```
int high = readInt(" Please insert the number: ");
                rgen = new RandomGenerator();
                int random = (int) rgen.nextInt(0, high);
                while (valid){
                    if(high<0) { 
                        println( " The highest value must be positive. ");
                        high = readInt(" Please insert the highest value: ");
                    }else if(ContainsPowerOfTwo(0, high)==false){
                        println(" There are no power of two numbers in this interval.");
                        println("-1");
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }else{  
                        valid=false;
                    }   
                }   

                while(flag2){
                    if(isPowerOfTwo(random) == false) {
                        rgen = new RandomGenerator();
                        random = (int) rgen.nextInt(0, high);
                    }else{
                        println(" The random generated number that is power of two is: " + random);
                        flag2=false;
                    }
                }
```

Can you please help me find the issue(s)?

Comment: Why do you have `isPowerOfTwo(int)` return false for 1? 1 is definitely a power of two.

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is correct. My bad, thank you. I changed it now.

Comment: check this magic here http://java67.blogspot.gr/2015/06/how-to-find-if-number-power-of-two.html

Comment: Not related with problem, but about coding style: `if (condition){return true; }else{ return false;}` can be replaced with simpler `return condition`. Also avoid `if (flag == true)`. It is very easy to make mistake like `if (flag = true)` where we assign `true` to `flag` making entire expression evaluated as `true`. It is better to write `if (flag)` or using Yoda style `if (true == flag)` - since we won't be able to assign anything to `true` with `true = ...`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'll keep it in mind. Funny thing is that I did this mistake `if (flag = true) ` 2 minutes ago and corrected it on my own!

Answer (score 4):

You can use Long functions to make this easier.

```
public static boolean powerOf2InRange(long low, long high) {
    return Long.bitCount(low) == 1 ||
            Long.bitCount(high) == 1 ||
            Long.highestOneBit(low) != Long.highestOneBit(high);
}
```

Comment: Yes, now that I think of it, you're right. Thing is that, even though it might sound a little stupid, I haven't been taught this, so I'm unsure if I should use it.

Comment: I've just came here to type this solution, but too late 'apparently'. Hehehe. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to assess the existence of a power of two and not its value, it would be enough by using [Bolzano's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem):

```
private static boolean ContainsPowerOfTwo(int low, int high){
    if(isPowerOfTwo(low) || isPowerOfTwo(high))
        // Checking the extremes
        return true;
    else
        // If the integer part of the logarithms are different, there must be a number within the interval where the logarithm is exact (Bolzano's theorem)
        return (Math.floor(log(high, 2)) > Math.floor(log(low, 2)))
}

private static double log(int x, int base) {
    return (Math.log(x) / Math.log(base));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code:

```
 for (int i = low; low <= high; i++){
    if ( (low & -low ) == low && low!=0 && low!=1 ) {
        f = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Would result in an infinite loop. Your `for` loop will run if `low <= high`, since your loop doesn't change the value of `low` this will always be true and your loop will run forever. I suspect you meant `i <= low`.

There are a few other areas which could be improved, but if that infinite loop is the case then perhaps overcoming that can get you started. Are you using an IDE? You can debug your code and step through it to see if the flow is as you'd expect. This should highlight where the code deviates from what you expect.

Comment: Damn.. Yes, that's what I meant. ( i <= low ). Now for some reason I get
the number I want but the message " There are not power of two numbers in this interal. -1 " pop up too

Comment: Great, well done. Hopefully I was of assistance in helping you see the solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm really grateful that I had you to tell me these things. Sometimes, even though you know what's correct and what's not, it seems so hard to be in the position to actually find your own mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

A bit different approach not to check all the values in the given interval. Because the function power-of-2 is strictly increasing, I have taken the log2 of the interval limits and checked them.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        containsPowerOfTwo(43, 64);
        containsPowerOfTwo(31, 63);
        containsPowerOfTwo(32, 63);
        containsPowerOfTwo(33, 63);
        containsPowerOfTwo(33, 64);
        containsPowerOfTwo(55, 127);
        containsPowerOfTwo(56, 128);
        containsPowerOfTwo(34, 127);
    }

    private static boolean containsPowerOfTwo(int low, int high) {
        double log2Low = log2(low);
//        System.out.println("log2Low: " + log2Low);
        double log2High = log2(high);
//        System.out.println("log2High: " + log2High);
        double floorlog2Low = Math.floor(log2Low);
//        System.out.println("floorlog2Low: " + floorlog2Low);
        double floorlog2High = Math.floor(log2High);
//        System.out.println("floorlog2High: " + floorlog2High);
        boolean retVal = log2High == floorlog2High || log2Low == floorlog2Low || floorlog2High - floorlog2Low >= 1;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d - %d %B ",low ,high, retVal));
        return retVal;
    }

    private static double log2(int value) {
        return Math.log(value) / Math.log(2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
43 - 64 TRUE 
31 - 63 TRUE 
32 - 63 TRUE 
33 - 63 FALSE 
33 - 64 TRUE 
55 - 127 TRUE 
56 - 128 TRUE 
34 - 127 TRUE
```